# C - Checking for NULL values

Tags: c, coding-style

I am coming across situations such as this:

```
if(x == NULL)
{
  printf(" The value of X is Null, exiting..");
  return -1;
}
```

and this "situation" gets repeated many , many times.....  laziness aside is there a better way to write this ?

Cheers!

Comment: The above check for a NULL value, can it be done via a MACRO ? Is that advisable...

Comment: Yes, it can be done with a macro, but that's _not_ advisable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going on your comment to @sbi, yes you can do this with a macro.

```
#define RETURN_MINUS_ONE_IF_NULL(x) \
do \
{\
    if (x == NULL) \
    { \
        printf(#x " is null, exiting\n"); \
        return -1; \
    } \
} \
while (0)
```

Then you would call this as

```
signed int foo (int *x)
{ 
    RETURN_MINUS_ONE_IF_NULL(x);

    /* ... */
}
```

HOWEVER, I would strongly advise against doing this - hiding a return from a function within a macro is very confusing to a casual reader.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately i can't go via assert route and this as you mentioned... looks too messy :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why a macro cannot be used, although it should be more general than checking for NULL pointers.

For instance,

#define FAIL(condition, msg) if ((condition)) { fprintf(stderr, (msg)); exit(1); }

Then you have,

FAIL(x == NULL, "could not instantiate x");

Answer (score 1):

In the case where this situation is not meant to happen *at all*, you are searching for the concept of assertions.

Consider the C "assert(int expr)" function. When "expr" is equals to 0 (expr is false, in a boolean world), the program will *exit* and will (generally) print the location where the assertion failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can support exiting the process when the pointer is null, you should use the assert function:

```
void assert(int expression);
```

Otherwise, the macro is the only way to handle this unfortunately.

Comment: `assert` is a macro too, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to write this is as a doxygen comment or an entry in whatever documentation system you use, informing callers of something that they should already know: `NULL` is not a valid pointer. Even there, rather than special-casing the remark that `NULL` is not valid, it makes more sense to simply document the argument `x` as being a valid pointer to type `foo`. This covers the billions of other invalid pointer values as well. Personally I prefer not to waste time documenting this requirement for every function but instead document as a general part of my library interfaces that, unless otherwise specified for a particular function, all pointer arguments must be valid pointers to objects of the corresponding type.

If you really do want to document this at the source level too, C99 has a way, using:

```
void foo(int x[static 1]);
```

instead of one of the following:

```
void foo(int *x);
void foo(int x[]);
```